# Excel: Set a maxium value for colour scale

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, analysis

I am trying to create a data analysis spreadsheet for some test results in a school. [image]

The picture above is some dummy data I am using. I need to highlight using a colour scale conditional formatting for each question, however I want the spreadsheet to know the maximum value and minimum value from the Marks row. The minimum mark for all questions is obviously 1, however the maximum for question 1 would be 3, for question 2 it would be 2 etc.

The problem is when using the stock colour scale, say if no one achieves full marks in a question, the highest mark even though not actual maximum would be highlighted green.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a rule for the range C6:C9 which colors the cell green if the value equals `C$3`. Then copy the cell format to the other cells.

Comment: Or add a hidden column which features the desired highest value and include it in your conditional formatting.